# LINQ - groupBy with items in several Group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object that has two properties, let's say `a` and `b`. `a` is an Enum like:

```
[Flags] enum MyEnum
{
    first  = 1,
    second = 2,
    third  = 4,
    fourth = 8
};
```

`b` is an unsigned integer, which is a *mask* (combination of the MyEnum flags).

now i need to sum every object by their `a` - meaning an object can be summed twice if `obj.a = first | third` and i can't seem to do a `groupBy` to them. is there a different way to sum them?

I'm sorry i don't share my code, but i can't. i can tell you i did it using foreach in just some if - else blocks but i think i should learn how to do it in Linq

**EDIT:**
I think i wasn't clear. i want to sum the object by the Enum, meaning if i have:

```
obj1.a = first, obj1.b = 5
obj2.a = first | second, obj2.b = 3
```

then the output will be

```
first sum = 8
second sum = 3
```

Comment: could you provide the expected result? your question is not really clear to me

Comment: Your problem is still not clear. What if we have `obj3 = first | second | third;` What are the sums? Can they be `first sum = 15`, `second sum = 8`, `third sum = 3`, `fourth sum = 7`, `fifth sum = 8`, `sixth sum = 14`?

Comment: @KingKing exactly. i sum by the enum values, so if an object has in the enum first|second|third and 3 in the value field then 3 will be added to the sum of first, second and third

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a `MyEnum` and a `MyClass`

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    first = 1,
    second = 2,
    third = 4,
    forth = 8
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyEnum MyEnum;
    public uint Value;
}
```

And some values

```
var mcs = new[] { 
    new MyClass { MyEnum = MyEnum.first | MyEnum.third, Value = 10 },
    new MyClass { MyEnum = MyEnum.second, Value = 20 },
    new MyClass { MyEnum = MyEnum.first, Value = 100 },
};
```

This LINQ expression will return for each value of the enum the sum of the values.

```
var ret = from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>() 
              select new { MyEnum = p, Sum = mcs.Where(q => q.MyEnum.HasFlag(p)).Sum(q => q.Value) };
```

Note that it will return a "row" even for `MyEnum.fourth` with value `0`.

The expression starts with the values of the enum (`Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()`) and then for each value it sums the values of the `mcs` that have the same `MyEnum` (`mcs.Where(q => q.MyEnum.HasFlag(p)).Sum(q => q.Value)`)

If you want to exclude the values of the enum that aren't used:

```
var ret = from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()
          let temp = mcs.Where(q => q.MyEnum.HasFlag(p)).Select(q => q.Value).ToArray()
          where temp.Length > 0
          select new { MyEnum = p, Sum = temp.Sum(q => q) };
```

The expression starts with the values of the enum (`Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()`) and then for each value it "saves" the values of the `mcs` that have the same `MyEnum` (`let temp = mcs.Where(q => q.MyEnum.HasFlag(p)).Select(q => q.Value).ToArray()`) in `temp`, skips the `temp` that are empty (`where temp.Length > 0`) and sum the remaining `temp` (`select new { MyEnum = p, Sum = temp.Sum(q => q) }`). Note that if you use an `uint` you have to use `temp.Sum(q => q)`, but with an `int` you can use `temp.Sum()` (or you can use `temp.Sum(q => q)`).

Another way is through a double `from` and a `group by`

```
var ret = from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()
          from q in mcs 
          where q.MyEnum.HasFlag(p)
          group q.Value by p into r
          select new { MyEnum = r.Key, Sum = r.Sum(p => p) };
```

It's probably equivalent to using the `SelectMany` as suggested by ChaseMedallion (a double `from` is converted by the compiler to a `SelectMany`)

Comment: wow, really thank you. very explained and good for future use too. excellent answer

Answer (score 3):

Try using HasFlag and GetValues to extract all the flags for a particular enum value:

```
var objs = new[] { new { a = MyEnum.first | MyEnum.second }, new { a = MyEnum.first }... };
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToArray();

// first, use SelectMany to create a sequence with one instance of each object for
// each flag value in it's a
var grouped = objs.SelectMany(
        o => enumValues.Where(flag => o.a.HasFlag(flag))
            .Select(v => new { o, flag })
    )
    // then group by the extracted flag value
    // the element selector (t => t.o) gets us back to an IGrouping of o's (dropping the extra flag property
    .GroupBy(t => t.flag, t => t.o);

 // finally, we can get sums by a as follows:
 var sumsByA = grouped.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(o => o.b));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, really good and explained, will try is ASAP